# Python script to add sequences together. Not including first element?

Tags: python, dictionary, append, sequence

For some reason it's not including the first entry and I can't figure out why ? When I use the first entry, i.e.

```
">mm10_ensGene_ENSMUST00000038432 range=chr1:172956768-172956796 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none"
```

in `D_ID_seq` dictionary, I get a keyerror .

**Why is it working for all others but not the first one?**

```
in_file = [">mm10_ensGene_ENSMUST00000038432 range=chr1:172956768-172956796 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none", 
           'TTTCCCCTTTTAGACACCCATAGAACAGA', 
           ">mm10_ensGene_ENSMUST00000060693 range=chr1:174089038-174089041 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none", 
           'AGCA', 
           ">mm10_ensGene_ENSMUST00000061990 range=chr1:174250926-174250976 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=- repeatMasking=none", 
           'CAACTGCCATGGTGGAAGGAACCAACAGGATCACAAGGACAATCATTCAG',
           'A', 
           ">mm10_ensGene_ENSMUST00000062353 range=chr1:92512027-92518515 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=- repeatMasking=none", 
           'CCACGTCCTCGCACATGGGGAAGGAAGCTTCCCTTTTCTCTCAGTGCCTC', 
           'CTTTAAACCAGCTGTGGCTCAAGTGGGCCAGCTGCTCTGAGGGATTAGCC', 
           'AGGCTGCAGCAGAAGCCAGGTGTCTGGGGGTGACAGTGGACAGAGAGAAG', 
           'TGGTTTCAGAAGACTGAGGACAGACACACAGACACCGGCAGATCTCCAAG']

IDs = []

D_ID_seq = {}
D_ID_EJnum = {}


for indx in range(0,len(in_file)):
    if in_file[indx][0] == '>':
        IDs.append(in_file[indx])
        temp_seq = ''
        while indx:
            for i in range((indx+1),len(in_file)):                
                if in_file[i][0] != '>':
                    temp_seq = temp_seq + in_file[i]
                else:
                    break  
            D_ID_seq[in_file[indx]] = temp_seq                
            break

print D_ID_seq.keys()
```

RESULTS

```
[">mm10_ensGene_ENSMUST00000062353 range=chr1:92512027-92518515 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=- repeatMasking=none", ">mm10_ensGene_ENSMUST00000061990 range=chr1:174250926-174250976 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=- repeatMasking=none", ">mm10_ensGene_ENSMUST00000060693 range=chr1:174089038-174089041 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none"]
```

Comment: probably the `range((indx+1),len(in_file))`?

Comment: that's what i'm thinking but i have to start at the index b/c if i stay at the "while" index value then it will include that one . . . definitely has a ">" at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `while` loop. For the first element of your list, `indx` is 0. 0 evaluates as `False` in a boolean context,  so your loop never executes for that first element. Since you never modify `indx` in the loop and rely on `break` to exit it, you can use `while True:` instead.

There are other algorithms for this kind of thing that don't reprocess the sequence lines, but that's the simplest change to your listed code.